# Does handler.post(runnable) start a new thread?

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

If the handler was instantiated in the main UI thread, does a post with a Runnable create a child thread that gets added to the message queue, or does it just get run in the UI thread?

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it doesn't create a new thread. It simply executes your runnable on the thread your handler is attached to, which in this case means your UI thread

Answer (score 0):

```
handler.post(new Runnable()){

public  void run(){
//do something
}
});
```

this does not guarantee that it will create a new thread.it will just call the runnable of the thread in which the handler is attached to(UI thread here).

Handler doesn't create a new thread, it binds to the looper of the thread that is it created in (the main thread in this case), or to a looper you give it during construction.